# Ansible - Repeat a list for N times

Tags: list, loops, ansible

I have a main playbook that use `include` to call other playbooks in case conditions are met. That is working fine, but what I need is to execute these playbooks for `n` times, where `n` is a user input variable. So, if the user enters "5", the main playbook will call playbooks for 5 times.

This is the example:

```yaml
---
- name: main playbook
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  var_files: weqwewq

  tasks:
    - include: 1.yml
      when: x == "aaa"
    - include: 2.yml
      when: x == "bbb"
    - include: 3.yml
      when: x == "ccc"
    - include: 4.yml
      when: x == "ddd"
```

What I don't need is this:

```yaml
      tasks:
        - include: 1.yml
          when: x == "aaa"
          with_sequence: count= "{{ user_input }}"
        - include: 2.yml
          when: x == "aaa+bbb"
          with_sequence: count= "{{ user_input }}"
        - include: 3.yml
          when: x == "ccc"
          with_sequence: count= "{{ user_input }}"
        - include: 4.yml
          when: x == "ccc+ddd"
          with_sequence: count= "{{ user_input }}"
```

but instead something like this

```yaml
    tasks:
      with_sequence: count= "{{ user_input }}"
        - include: 1.yml
          when: x == "aaa"
        - include: 2.yml
          when: x == "aaa+bbb"
        - include: 3.yml
          when: x == "ccc"
        - include: 4.yml
          when: x == "ccc+ddd"
```

but for this I'm getting an error:

"with_sequence is not a valid attribute for a play".

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `include` level, and add your sequence loop to that task.

---

First, note that the `include` module [has been deprecated](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_module.html#deprecated). You should be using `include_tasks`.

To loop over your tasks with a single loop construct, start with a top-level playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: tasks.yaml
      with_sequence: count=5
```

In `tasks.yaml`, place your `include_tasks` with conditions:

```
- name: show loop index
  debug:
    var: item

- include_tasks: tasks_1.yaml
  when: x = 'aaa'
- include_tasks: tasks_2.yaml
  when: x = 'bbb'
- include_tasks: tasks_3.yaml
  when: x = 'ccc'
```

And then create the individual `task_N.yaml` files as necessary

Comment: Thanks! 

Here is some extension of the problem, maybe you can help with this too?

I want to change some variable in each cycle, so if there is just one run / cycle it would be "01" and if it is the 5th run it would be "05"... How can I do this?

Comment: Inside the loop, the variable `item` will contain the current loop index. I've updated the answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Interactive Input`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) to take N as input. Also, you might consider checking [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#playbooks-variables) for more information on the usage of variables in ansible.

Also, it is a [good practice](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html) to use tasks to organize your code.
Check the following code:

**Update:** I added `stride` parameter in `with_sequence` so now increment value can be set other than 1 (default).

**Your main playbook file:**

```
---
- name: main playbook
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars_prompt:

    - name: counter
      prompt: Enter loop counter
      private: no


  tasks:
    - include_tasks: tasks.yml
      with_sequence: start=1 end="{{ counter }}" stride="{{ 1 }}"
```

**The additional `tasks.yml`:**

```
---

- include_tasks: 1.yml
  when: 
    - x is defined
    - x = "aaa"
- include_tasks: 2.yml
  when:
    - x is defined 
    - x = "bbb"
- include_tasks: 3.yml
  when:
    - x is defined
    - x = "ccc"
- include_tasks: 4.yml
  when:
    - x is defined
    - x = "ddd"
```

Here in `tasks.yml` I added conditionals to check whether x is defined.

Comment: Thank you. Environment I'm using is Ansible Tower and there is user survey from which I get the number of needed cycles.

However I need to increment some other variable with each cycle, so it starts with 1 in a first cycle and then increments by 1... Any idea on this?

Comment: @LJS Check my updated code. I added the extra option 'stride' inside with_sequence to control the increment value. But, as of now, it is a static value. Regarding dynamically increasing stride, I don't know how it can be done. Fortunately, there are more expert persons in the community. Someone will definitely help you!

Comment: I already made it work with the other proposed solution, but this would do the work too. I will note it for future usage. Thanks.